# In IE 7 background shift to 1 px top to but in FF it's ok?

Tags: css

In IE 7 background shift to 1 px top to but in FF it's ok?

```
 background: url(girl.jpg) top left repeat-x;
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;color: #666;
 border-bottom-color: white;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
      top:0px;
    *top:1px;

*background-position:0px 1px;
```

- work only four IE7 so you can use this.

you can enter value according your design. in *top: px.

Comment: have you add this code in your css. you can set top value like *top:-1px. try it. or have you try this

Comment: `*top:-1px` i think it's can't control background position

Comment: *background-position:0px 1px;
use  this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this comes from the background image. Are you sure there is no transparent border, or other 1px shift elsewhere in the markup?

Comment: @metal but that couldn't cause a shift in the *top*, could it?

Answer (score 0):

IE6 has bugs with positioning background on relative positioned elements. Is your document in standards mode? And try giving your element hasLayout e.g. with `zoom: 1`.

Comment: yes `zoom:1` solve the background problem but it breaks the layoyt

Comment: You'll need to rework the layout then, so that it works with hasLayout :-(